# Wait for keyboard press without blocking

Tags: haskell

My current simple TCP echo server code looks like this

```
import Network.Socket

main :: IO ()
main = setup

setup :: IO ()
setup = do
    sock <- socket AF_INET Stream 0
    bind sock (SockAddrInet 5000 iNADDR_ANY);
    listen sock 5
    loop sock

loop :: Socket -> IO()
loop sock = do
    conn                    <- accept sock
    handleConnection conn
    loop sock

handleConnection :: (Socket, SockAddr) -> IO ()
handleConnection (clntSock, clntAddr) = do
    putStrLn $ "Handling client: " ++ show clntAddr
    clntMsg <- recv clntSock 256
    _ <- send clntSock clntMsg
    close clntSock
```

The loop runs forever. I tried few methods to listen for keyboard press and then exit. But they all blocked main loop. So that server wasn't responding to client and was just waiting for key press.

How to interact with command line while still serving clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [wait for input](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#v:hWaitForInput), probably on [standard in](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#v:stdin).

Modifying your existing code ever so slightly:

```
loop sock = do
    conn <- accept sock
    handleConnection conn
    done <- hWaitForInput stdin 1
    if done then return () else loop sock
```

You'll also need to add this import:

```
import System.IO (hWaitForInput, stdin)
```

Comment: Might also use [hReady](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#v:hReady).